# Is there any method to get the information of a module in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, module

```
module FAM where
```

I have no idea what FAM does. So I want to get some information about it.

By using `:t` and `:i`, we will get the type of a variable and the information of an instance respectively. Is there any method to get the information of a module?

Comment: try :browse FAM

Comment: I got an error message `Could not find module ‘FAM’
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.` I tried `:browse Data` as well. And also got the same error.

Comment: Where is this FAM module? Is it a standalone file? in a cabal package? I'd try to compile it and load in GHCi first. I'd also try to generate haddock docs.

Comment: It's from my [lecture](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~trebla/CSCC24-2018-Summer/FAM.hs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A module doesn't have a type, it just exports declarations.  If you want to see what declarations it exports (in a manner other than clicking the link you already have) then load the module in GHCi and browse it.

For example, I have your FAM module saved in my tmp directory so I can load it in GHCi:

```
% ghci /tmp/FAM.hs
GHCi, version 8.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /Users/tommd/.ghci
[1 of 1] Compiling FAM              ( /tmp/FAM.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*FAM>
```

Now I can ask for the declarations exported by the module with browse either leaving the module implicit (`:browse`) or specifying the module I'm interested in (`:browse FAM`) which is useful if more than one module is loaded. For example:

```
*FAM> :browse FAM
fmap_List :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
fmap_Maybe :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
fmap_Either :: (a -> b) -> Either e a -> Either e b
data BinTree a = BTNil | BTNode a (BinTree a) (BinTree a)
map2_List :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
map2_Maybe :: (a -> b -> c) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe c
map2_Either ::
  (a -> b -> c) -> Either e a -> Either e b -> Either e c
ap_List :: [a -> b] -> [a] -> [b]
map2_Listv2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
map3_List :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [d]
addRecip :: Double -> Double -> Maybe Double
bind_Maybe :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
bind_Either :: Either e a -> (a -> Either e b) -> Either e b
bind_List :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]
data IntranetRecord = I Integer String
data BBRecord = B Integer String
data MarkUsRecord = M String String
myJoin :: [IntranetRecord] -> [BBRecord] -> [MarkUsRecord]
myJoin2 :: [IntranetRecord] -> [BBRecord] -> [MarkUsRecord]
foldM :: Monad m => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> [a] -> m b
newtype State s a = StateOf (s -> (s, a))
deState :: State s a -> s -> (s, a)
put :: s -> State s ()
get :: State s s
statefulSum :: [Integer] -> State Integer Integer
toyCheck :: IO Bool
class Monad f => MonadToyCheck (f :: * -> *) where
  toyGetChar :: f Char
  {-# MINIMAL toyGetChar #-}
toyCheck2 :: MonadToyCheck f => f Bool
realProgram :: IO Bool
newtype Feeder a = F (String -> (String, a))
unF :: Feeder a -> String -> (String, a)
testToyChecker2 :: String -> Bool
```

From here you can inspect the types, classes, and functions exported by your module.